# Swift search bar issue

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view controller that grabs json data from a website and displays the values of each record as a row.  The TVC has a search bar delegate that allows you to search for records by name.  Everything works okay except when you click on a record that is filtered (that is, you enter a search value in the search bar and click through the filtered list) it takes you to the wrong record. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but any help appreciated

```
import UIKit

class SearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var searchActive : Bool = false
var filtered:[String] = []
var filteredURLs:[String] = []
var filteredName:[String] = []

var TableData2:Array< String > = Array < String >()
var TableData2URLs:Array< String > = Array < String >()
var TableDataName:Array< String > = Array < String >()


var passedValue:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Search"
    get_data_from_url(passedValue)

    /* Setup delegates */
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self

}

// functions added for search bar
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true;
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = TableData2.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    filteredURLs = TableData2URLs.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    filteredName = TableDataName.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })

    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

// End search bar code

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if(searchActive) {
        return filtered.count
    } else {
    return TableData2.count
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    if(searchActive){
        cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
    } else {
    cell.textLabel?.text = TableData2[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}


func get_data_from_url(url:String)
{
    let httpMethod = "GET"
    let timeout = 15
    let url = NSURL(string: url)
    let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 15.0)
    let queue = NSOperationQueue()
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(
        urlRequest,
        queue: queue,
        completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,
            data: NSData!,
            error: NSError!) in
            if data.length > 0 && error == nil{
                let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
                self.extract_json(json!)
            }else if data.length == 0 && error == nil{
                println("Nothing was downloaded")
            } else if error != nil{
                println("Error happened = \(error)")
            }
        }
    )
}

func extract_json(data:NSString)
{
    var parseError: NSError?
    let jsonData:NSData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
    let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &parseError)
    if (parseError == nil)
    {
        if let countries_list = json as? NSArray
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < countries_list.count ; i++ )
            {
                if let country_obj = countries_list[i] as? NSDictionary
                {
                    if let country_name = country_obj["country"] as? String
                    {
                        if let country_code = country_obj["region"] as? String
                        {
                            if let namevalue = country_obj["name"] as? String {
                                TableData2.append(namevalue + ": " + country_name )
                                TableData2URLs.append("http://www.example.com/jsondetail.php?value=" + namevalue)
                                TableDataName.append(namevalue)
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    do_table_refresh();
}


func do_table_refresh()
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        return
    })
}


// Pass url details for Segue
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController  as! DetailViewController

        let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let row = myIndexPath?.row

        if(searchActive && row < filteredURLs.count){

            detailViewController.webSite = filteredURLs[row!]
            detailViewController.name = filteredName[row!]
            detailViewController.title = filteredName[row!]

            println("Filtered URL: " + filteredURLs[row!])
            println(row)
            println("Filtered Name: " + filteredName[row!])
            println(row)

        } else {

            detailViewController.webSite = TableData2URLs[row!]
            detailViewController.name = TableDataName[row!]
            detailViewController.title = TableDataName[row!]
            println("Table URL: " + TableData2URLs[row!])
            println(row)

        }






    }
}


}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be when and where you are setting searchActive = false. Try only setting it to false (besides initialization) when the searchText.count == 0

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating things and not using objects correctly, You should create an object that encapsulates all the data you need, so that one instance of that class can hold all the data you need for each cell. So your datasource is an array of these object, e.g. [Country], and another for the filtered Countries. This forms the model. You might want to store that data too, so you could serialize the objects. I would start with that and then see how it goes. You are splitting everything up into 6 different arrays, 3 for each result set. Its making everything more complicated.

Something that would help you is also the cleaner way to write if let, e.g.

```
func extract_json(data:NSString)
{
    var parseError: NSError?
    let jsonData:NSData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
    let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &parseError)

    if (parseError == nil)
    {
        if let countries_list = json as? NSArray
       {
            for i in 0..<countries_list.count
            {
                if let country_obj = countries_list[i] as? NSDictionary,
                country_name = country_obj["country"] as? String,
                country_code = country_obj["region"] as? String,
                namevalue = country_obj["name"] as? String 
                {
                     TableData2.append(namevalue + ": " + country_name )
                     TableData2URLs.append("http://www.example.com/jsondetail.php?value=" + namevalue)
                     TableDataName.append(namevalue)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    do_table_refresh();
}
```

Regarding the issue of the selection. Are you sure the urls are all being filtered correctly?